# how to alter sequence in db2 stored procedure by another user

Tags: db2, db2-luw, sequence

I am using DB2 LUW Version 10.5.0.5 on Linux (x86_64)
I have written a procedure to alter a sequence to restart with a certain number. The procedure takes the sequence name and the number to restart with as parameters.
The procedure got created successfully . I granted a developer connect access on the database and execute access on the procedure. But he is getting SQL -551 (permission issue for alter sequence sql) when he executes the procedure. 
Create table works perfectly fine when it is executed in a procedure by anyone who even doesnt have create table access. WHy alter doesn't work then? Is there a way to allow developers to alter a sequence in a database without granting alter access on the sequence itself?

Answer (score 2):

[Effect of DYNAMICRULES bind option on dynamic SQL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/c0007210.html)

You must set the `DYNAMICRULES` bind option to `BIND` before the routine creation to make dynamic sql statements of the routine execute with the routine creator authorization. They are executed with authorization of a user who runs the routine otherwise.
You can do it by calling the following statement before the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` statement in the same session:

```
CALL SET_ROUTINE_OPTS('DYNAMICRULES BIND')
```

But you are not able to execute dynamically the following statements with such a bind option as described in `Table 2. Definitions of Dynamic SQL Statement Behaviors`:

```
GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, CREATE, DROP, COMMENT ON, RENAME, SET INTEGRITY, and SET EVENT MONITOR STATE
```

This means, that you are not able to run dynamically `ALTER SEQUENCE` with an authorization different from the invoker's one.
You may grant `ALTER` privilege on sequence to your developer to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Really appreciate your help. However, the solution didnt work.  I ran call set_routine_opts('DYNAMICRULES BIND') in the same session as create procedure as dbadm user. Upon calling the procedure with dev userid, I am getting error "SQL0549N  The "ALTER" statement is not allowed for "package" "<package name>"
because the bind option DYNAMICRULES RUN is not in effect for the "package".
SQLSTATE=42509"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that some statements can't be executed in such a routine. I've updated the answer.